# When I load an aspx page using jQuery model, I am unable use the server side methods of that aspx page

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, modal-dialog, popupwindow

When I load an aspx page to a popwindow using jQuery model using below code.

```
function OpenExceptions() {
$('#Equipmentdialog').load('Popups/Test1.aspx', function () {
   $(this).dialog({
        modal: true,
        width: 900,
        height: 400
    });
});
```

}

I am unable to call any server side method(C# button click) in the Test1.Aspx method, When I call the the server side events, I am getting resource not found exception?

Can someone please explain me what is the reason?

Thanks

Update: this is the error I am getting

[image]

Comment: This is definitely possible. Post the exception details, including the full stack trace.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/lh2pkrdiwfb2ulj/Jquery_TestWeb_app.zip

Comment: I have created a simple project replicating this issue, if you not able to access it let me know will how else i can share it will share it with you.

Comment: Mr. @Oleg Any help here?

Answer (score 0):

I looked at your sample project and the issue you are experiencing is very simple to explain but I am afraid it's not going to be so simple to make it work.

First I'll explain what's causing the exception.

When the dialog loads, it sets its content to whatever output is generated by the `Test.aspx` page. Since the page generates this HTML when you navigate to it:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head><title>

</title></head>
<body>
    <form name="form1" method="post" action="Test.aspx" id="form1">
<div>
<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="/wEPDwUKMTI2NTY4ODI3MWRkmRTYlsUe3rVbAI2jDoNeA5EPuo8=" />
</div>

<div>

    <input type="hidden" name="__EVENTVALIDATION" id="__EVENTVALIDATION" value="/wEWAgKd2MeEBAKM54rGBl+Fr2fdw6uP6072WYTIw/gz9N5E" />
</div>
    <div>
        <span id="Label1">Label</span>
        <br />
        <br />
        <input type="submit" name="Button1" value="Button" id="Button1" />

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

The dialog ends up displaying a form whose action is set to `Test.aspx`; therefore, when you click on the `Button` on the dialog, it attempts to post back the form to `Test.aspx` but it doesn't find it because this page is inside `Popups/Test.aspx`. Now, in order to "fix it" (I say this in quotes because it's not really going to fix anything), you could change the dialog's HTML by brute force; doing something like this:

```
function OpenExceptions() {
            $('#Equipmentdialog').load('Popups/Test.aspx #form1', function (response, status, xhr) {
                response = response.replace('action="Test.aspx"', 'action="Popups/Test.aspx"'); //Make sure the form's action is accurate
                $(this).html(response);
                $(this).dialog({
                    modal: true,
                    width: 900,
                    height: 400
                });
            });
        }
```

And now, when you click the `Button` you will no longer receive a `Resource Not Found Exception`; however, because this causes a normal post back **the dialog will disappear**, the button will post back the page and the label you have on the page will display the current date and time.

Again, this all happens because you are doing normal post backs as opposed to Ajax requests. My approach above would work if the `Button` in the `Test.aspx` page performs an Ajax request but not the kind you get when you use Update Panels and Script Managers. You won't be able to use those tools because of the way they work internally...

If you are looking to use Ajax in your app, I recommend you look at WCF Web Services in conjunction with JQuery. There are many good tutorials online on the topic.

I hope my answer at least helps you understand why this isn't working for you and why it won't work if you continue to use this approach. There are many hacks that you could apply to make it work, but I can't think of a single one that's going to be easy to maintain and scale going forward. The best approach is to do Ajax properly, using WCF web services (or Page Methods) and JQuery.